# article + personal pronoun: "After I lose some weight, I will be <a> lighter me."

Tags: articles, personal-pronouns

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-nato.2440199/post-12273297):
**(1)** *After I lose some weight, I will be **a** lighter me*.
my variant:
**(2)** *After I lose some weight, I will be lighter me*.

"A" is an article, so it cannot be before a personal pronoun. Why is (1) correct?

Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Neither of them are really "correct". They're both somewhat peculiar / facetious alternatives to idiomatically standard ***...I will be lighter.*** But #1 is less "unusual" than #2, which effectively treats "lighter me" as a quirky proper noun (the way that if someone bigger than ***Big John*** joined a group, he might be facetiously dubbed ***Bigger John***).

Comment: I will be **a** lighter [**version of**] me.

Comment: (2) is wonderfully Geordie. ;) [Stereotypical dialect trait that any sentence about yourself ends with 'me', whether it fits or not.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, "me" means "version of myself", rather than its normal meaning, so it's correct with "a", and incorrect without it.

> After I lose some weight, I will be **a** lighter version of myself.
> <del>After I lose some weight, I will be __ lighter version of myself.</del>

The use of "me" as a regular countable noun in this way, rather than following the normal rules of pronouns, [started in the 1980s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20new%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). It was humorously bad grammar, and everyone knew it. This usage caught on though, and, in my opinion, it has achieved acceptance, though it's not in Oxford or Merriam-Webster.

Comment: You use "myself". Is "_After I lose some weight, I will be a lighter **myself**_." correct too? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii Well.... kinda. I've added a paragraph about this usage of "me" to my answer. If you use "myself" in this way today, again, people will understand it, but it will be considered bad grammar, though no worse than "a lighter me" was in the 1980s.

Answer (score 3):

That's because "me" isn't being used as the personal pronoun.  It's being used as a noun, and so capable of being determined (with an article) and modified (with an adjective).

This is rather odd and rare.  Normally "me" is very clearly a pronoun. And pronouns don't behave like nouns. But here the speaker wants to refer to "the person who I may potentially become"  And this requires a noun (since this person isn't the speaker).  The solution is to use "me" but treat it as a noun.

Other languages don't treat pronouns specially, and could be said not to have pronouns, merely nouns that refer to the speaker. And so these languages don't have have this issue.